# "What [style] schools are there in [location]?"

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it acceptable to ask which schools teach a specific style in a certain area, or is that too localized?

e.g. "What Wing Chun schools are there in Yorkshire, UK?" or "Recommendations for Hapkido schools in Los Angeles?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's too localized. You could just as well do a search of local business listings and be done with it. Businesses may not stick around forever. New ones might pop up, or they might change locations which means that answers will also change over time.

Also, the SE Q&A model isn't good for "recommendations" and those questions are likely to be closed as "Not Constructive." Those questions will solicit opinions, and there are plenty other websites that can provide that for you.

Comment: sometimes I think it would be nice if the "stacks" had a forum as well, for discussion type things.

Comment: chat doesn't quite cut it

Comment: You can't just do a search for certain types of schools. Some that are very business focused might have websites and online listings, but there are a number of schools that you'd only find out by word of mouth. And what is there that can't be googled?