# Pushing out the FAQ

Tags: discussion, status-completed, faq, scope

Since there has been a lot of discussion regarding the scope of the site in the past, I think it is time to push out something concrete and organize what has been presented thus far. Based on what [Nick proposed](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/85/15), I've fleshed out something a little more thorough.

**Note:** Some of these linked meta posts are for reference. Not all of them have to exist in the FAQ, but some might be useful.

<s>**Edit:** I've proposed the FAQ as a community wiki answer. Please feel free to update it and add/remove content as necessary. The first proposed version will live in [this question revision](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/146/1). I want to give this about a week before pushing it out.</s>

**Update:** Since it has been about a week, I'm going to be pushing this out to the actual [faq](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/faq). There haven't been too many updates or feedback, but the ones made have been helpful. Any future amendments to the faq should be raised in a new meta post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martial Arts is a site for students and teachers — beginners, experts, professionals, and enthusiasts — of all martial arts. If you have a question about…

- Characteristics, regimens, [history](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/is-martial-arts-history-on-topic-of-off-topic), and [culture](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/lion-dancing-on-topic-or-not) of martial arts systems worldwide
- Execution, instruction, and practice of techniques (with or without weapons)
- [Martial arts equipment](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/103/15) (including use, maintenance, and construction)
- [Analysis of tactics and strategies from historical competitions, tournaments, and sparring matches](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/are-questions-about-specific-martial-arts-matches-on-topic)
- [Evaluating and choosing martial arts given specific criteria](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/15) (e.g. grappling, high kicks, self-defense, etc.)
- [Conducting or teaching martial arts classes, workshops, or seminars](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/are-questions-related-to-running-martial-arts-classes-on-topic)
- [Injury prevention within the context of martial arts training](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/are-questions-about-treating-injuries-off-topic)

…then feel free to ask. Please do a [search](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/search/) to check that no one else has asked first, though.

Questions that should **not be asked on Martial Arts** include:

- Recommendations for [schools](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/what-style-schools-are-there-in-location) or teachers in area *X* (too localized)
- What martial arts system is "best" or if you should practice art *A* instead of art *B* (not constructive)
- Theatrical or stage combat that focus more on theater or entertainment (for role-playing, re-enactments, etc.) (off-topic)
- [Fitness issues unrelated to martial arts](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30/15) (off-topic, please ask on [Fitness & Nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/))
- Martial arts movies, comics, science fiction, or fantasy (off-topic, please ask on [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) or [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/))
- [Business aspects of running a martial arts school](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/70/15) (legal advice, retention, location, advertising, etc.) (off-topic)
- General injury treatment or medical advice (off-topic)
- [If martial artist A would beat martial artist B](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) (not constructive)

Above all, remember that your question should have a clear answer. It should not prompt extended debate or invite opinion. If your question is not related to an actual problem you face or trends away from martial arts to a different subject, it probably does not belong on this site.

If you are unsure whether the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) of your question is appropriate for the site or not, feel free to bring it up on the [Martial Arts Meta](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/) for discussion.